# Single Article menu item - inconsistent weirdness in paging through articles list

Tags: menu-item, pagination

We have many clients on Joomla sites. Not sure exactly when this started, but in sites on the latest Joomla version (3.4.8), we are encountering inconsistent weirdness when trying to choose an article for a Single Article menu item.

On one site, we can't page through the list of articles there at all. E.g. click on page 3, list reloads but still on page 1.

On another site, we can page through the list unless we filter it. With the filter applied, can't page.

Not seeing any JavaScript errors in the console. Not logging any PHP errors.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue in Joomla see issues:
[#8364](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/8364)
 and [#8751](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/8751)

Update your Joomla to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, found after updated to 3.4.8. I solved it after fixing the database(extension->manage->database->fix). After fixing it to the lastest one, the problem is gone. Please clean your session after updating because the pagination info is recorded in session.  Hope this help.